# Using python Output in R for bar plots

Tags: r, python-2.7, plot

I want to use output from python program and barplot it using R.
I tried using rPy2

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
A= 2
B=4
plot = robjects.IntVector([A,D])
```

now to call barplot(plot) function. Please guide, even help using any other python package is appreciated

Comment: I don't get it. Are you asking how to call the barplot function, or did you call it and it didn't work?

Comment: I want to know, HOW to call it

Comment: The example under "functions" in the rpy2 documentation /is/ plotting - http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/robjects_functions.html - did it not work?